# How to get complete error message in xCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, stack-trace, nsexception

I am getting the following error message in Xcode:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

This is all that is shown. **How can I see a stack trace? Is there some Xcode option I can enable to see more information about this error?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, just figured it out! After the `(llbd)` in the console enter `bt`.